# How can i disable the compositor (gnome-shell/mutter) on fullscreen windows?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, fullscreen, gnome-shell

How can i disable the compositor (gnome-shell/mutter) on fullscreen windows ?
There is a bug on gnome-shell and gives me so bad performance in 3d games  !!!
AWFULLY LOW PERFORMANCE !!!
Is there a way to disable compositor redirection of full screen windows ?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this part by disabling vsync because by default mutter enables it to do this.

1. Create a file in `/etc/profile.d/` (name it as `script.sh`):

   ```
   export CLUTTER_VBLANK=none
   ```

   This will disable mutter’s vsync.
2. Log out then log back in again.

If this doesn't help you then all you can do is use Compiz. But to use Compiz you have to use another desktop environment in Ubuntu but not Unity as it is no longer supported.