# Ubuntu 20.04 Newb - Screen Flickering in Full-screen Games

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, games, steam

Afternoon all,

I've recently taken the plunge and have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a fresh install, after MS crashed after updates for the 3rd time in 18 months.

Steam installed okay, and have noticed if I run games full-screen, it periodically (every 3-10 seconds) flickers to black momentarily. Keeps doing it almost randomly, and with or without keyboard input so don't think this is a factor. If I run in windowed mode it works without issue, but not ideal as it doesn't display using the full screen. Tried it in a couple of games (KSP, Transport Fever 2), and same exact behaviour in both.

I read that the standard bundeled Nvidia drivers aren't great for gaming, so I've pushed through the latest version from the Beta bench (450). This hasn't seemed to fix it though, so a little perplexed.

I have some basic understanding of Linux, but am scratching my head as to what could be causing it. I have a g-sync monitor, so wondered if this might be part of the issue (I have tried enabling and disabling g-sync in the Nvidia settings, and doesn't seem to make a difference.)

Full spec available if needed, but basic spec below;

-i7-7700K on Asus Maximus IX Hero board (running latest BIOS)

-32GB Corsair Vengence DDR4-3000 RAM

-Asus Poseidon GTX 1080Ti Graphics card

Thanks.

Adam

Comment: Check in `nvidia-settings` if You have `g-sync` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its the right answer, but here are some things you can try:

1. Disable composting: [How can i disable the compositor (gnome-shell/mutter) on fullscreen windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969073/how-can-i-disable-the-compositor-gnome-shell-mutter-on-fullscreen-windows)
2. Search for tear free rendering. Eg: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418922/how-to-get-tear-free-rendering-with-nvidia-proprietary

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1754284
Possible workaround:
Alt+F2
lg [enter]
Meta.disable_unredirect_for_display(global.display) [enter]